# Counterexamples to the Grothendieck group of a commutative monoid respecting tensor products

Tags: solution-verification, tensor-products, semigroups, monoid, algebraic-k-theory

$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$Recall the definitions of the [tensor product $\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}$ of commutative monoids](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+product+of+commutative+monoids) (see also [this note by Harold Simmons](http://library.lol/main/FD1D94B2795B6E1B9CD504C9F69EEC7A)) and of the [Grothendieck group $K_0$ of a commutative monoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+group+of+a+commutative+monoid) (see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group)). Given commutative monoids $A$ and $B$, we can apply the universal property of $K_0$ to the diagram

[image]

to get a morphism of abelian groups
$$K^{\otimes}_{0|A,B}\colon K_{0}(A\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}B)\to K_{0}(A)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}K_{0}(B).$$
Since we also have an isomorphism $K^{\otimes,1}_{0}\colon K_{0}(\mathbb{N})\overset{\sim}{\dashrightarrow}\mathbb{Z}$, these morphisms endow $K_{0}$ with the structure of an oplax monoidal functor
$$
                (K_{0},K^{\otimes}_{0},K^{\otimes,1}_{0})
                \colon
                (\mathsf{CMon},\otimes_{\mathbb{N}},\mathbb{N})
                \longrightarrow
                (\mathsf{Ab},\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}},\mathbb{Z}).
$$
(I think―I haven't actually checked the coherence conditions.)

Now, I'm quite confident that the map $K^\otimes_{0|A,B}$ is not always an isomorphism, so I'm trying to come up with a counterexample. Am I correct in thinking that $A=B=(\mathbb{Z},\cdot,1)$ is such an example?

On one side, we have $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}\overset{\text{i think?}}{\cong}\Z\oplus\Z_{2}$, so
\begin{align*}
K_0(\Z\otimes_{\N}\Z) &\cong K_0(\Z\oplus\Z_2)\\
                      &\cong K_0(\Z)\oplus K_{0}(\Z_2)\\
                      &\cong \Q\oplus\Z_2,
\end{align*}
(where we've used the [strong monoidality of $K_0$ with respect to direct sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703033)), while on the other we have
\begin{align*}
K_0(\Z)\otimes_{\Z}K_0(\Z) &\cong \Q\otimes_{\Z}\Q\\
                           &\cong \Q
\end{align*}
(via [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458264)). Thus
$$K_0(\Z\otimes_{\N}\Z)\cong\Q\oplus\Z_2\neq\Q\cong K_0(\Z)\otimes_{\Z}K_0(\Z).$$

---

### Question

Are the above calculations correct? Moreover, what are some other examples (assuming this is indeed one >_<) of commutative monoids $A$ and $B$ such that the map $K_{0}(A\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}B)\to K_{0}(A)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}K_{0}(B)$ is not an isomorphism?

Comment: (Note that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084985) is quite similar to mine, but different)

Comment: I don't know where you're getting $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ from.  In any case, all the Grothendieck groups in your example are going to be trivial since you are inverting *every* element, including $0$, and inverting $0$ kills everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the canonical map $K_{0}(A\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}B)\to K_{0}(A)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}K_{0}(B)$ is always an isomorphism.  One way to see this is by observing that if $M$ is a commutative monoid then $K_0(M)$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{N}} M$ (where here $\mathbb{Z}$ is the additive monoid).  You can prove this, for instance, by verifying that bilinear maps $\mu:\mathbb{Z}\times M\to N$ are in natural bijection with homomorphisms $f:M\to N$ that send each element of $M$ to an invertible element (by defining $\mu(a,m)=af(m)$ in one direction and defining $f(m)=\mu(1,m)$ in the other direction).

So, $$K_0(A\otimes_\mathbb{N} B)\cong \mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{N} A\otimes_{\mathbb{N}} B\cong (\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z})\otimes_\mathbb{N} A\otimes_{\mathbb{N}} B\cong (\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{N} A)\otimes_\mathbb{N}(\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{N} B)\cong K_0(A)\otimes_\mathbb{N} K_0(B).$$  Since $\otimes_\mathbb{N}$ is the same as $\otimes_\mathbb{Z}$ when applied to commutative monoids that are actually already groups, this gives an isomorphism $K_{0}(A\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}B)\to K_{0}(A)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}K_{0}(B)$.  It is then a matter of definition-chasing to confirm that this isomorphism is the same as the map you are considering (for instance, by verifying that they both send elements of the form $[a\otimes b]$ (which generate the group $K_{0}(A\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}B)$) to $[a]\otimes [b]$)).

There are several errors in your proposed example.  I'm not sure how you got that $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$; this does not seem correct since (for instance) the elements $p\otimes -1$ should be distinct invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$ for each prime $p$ whereas $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ has only finitely many invertible elements (assuming you mean the $\mathbb{Z}$ there to still be the multiplicative monoid).  Also, $K_0(\mathbb{Z})=0$, not $\mathbb{Q}$, since adjoining an inverse to $0$ kills everything ($0\cdot x=0$ implies $x=1$ if $0$ becomes invertible).

Comment: Oh, this is excellent! Thank you! Would it be okay to ask a few more questions? 1) Why does $p$ need to be prime for $p\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}-1$ to be invertible in $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$? 2) On $K_0$'s and inverses of $0$, do we still have $K_0(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})\cong\mathbb{Q}^\times$? 3) Lastly, how does one describe $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ explicitly (with $\mathbb{Z}$ again the multiplicative monoid)? (I think I'm still a bit confused about how to think about tensor products of commutative monoids :/)

Comment: 1) Eh, $p$ probably doesn't need to be prime.  I was just thinking about primes specifically since they're the free generators of $\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$. 2) Yes, that's correct.

Comment: 3) I don't know the exact description.  If you removed $0$ from both copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ then they would each be isomorphic to a direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb{N}$ and one copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  When you tensor these together you get countably many copies of each of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ since tensor products distribute over direct sums.  But then to actually get $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$, you have to add back in all the elements and relations you get by including $0$.  I don't know a clean description of the result of that.

Comment: I believe that the natural map $(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})\otimes(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})\to\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}$ should be injective, so adding in $0$ doesn't give any new relations among the elements you already had.  But I haven't worked out a complete proof of that.

Comment: I think of tensor products of commutative monoids very similarly to how I think of tensor products of abelian groups (or of modules over a ring).  My core intution for how to think about $A\otimes B$ (if $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups, say) is that you describe how to "build" $A$ out of $\mathbb{Z}$ (more formally, by "building" I mean taking colimits), and then do the same thing but starting with $B$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$.  One way to make this precise is the Eilenberg-Watts theorem, which says $-\otimes B$ is the unique colimit-preserving functor $Ab\to Ab$ that sends $\mathbb{Z}$ to $B$.

Comment: For commutative monoids, you do the same thing, except the role of $\mathbb{Z}$ is played by $\mathbb{N}$ instead.  So for instance, what is $\mathbb{Z}\otimes M$ (where here $\mathbb{Z}$ is additive)?  Well, $\mathbb{Z}$ is obtained from $\mathbb{N}$ by adjoining an inverse to its generator, so $\mathbb{Z}\otimes M$ should be obtained by adjoining inverses to the generators of $M$, which just gives the Grothendieck group.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your way of thinking about tensor products of commutative monoids/abelian groups is really nice! I'll go learn about the Eilenberg–Watts theorem to try to understand your point of view better :)

Comment: (By the way, I've opened another question about explicitly describing $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217003), pointing to this discussion. This sounds like something with a very good chance of having been worked out before, so I think there's some value in asking it as a separate question―maybe someone already knows the answer. Also, I really like the description of $(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})$ you mentioned. Again, thank you so much!)