# Explicit description of $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, semigroups, monoid

$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$Recall the definition of the [tensor product $\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}$ of commutative monoids](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+product+of+commutative+monoids) (see also [this note by Harold Simmons](http://library.lol/main/FD1D94B2795B6E1B9CD504C9F69EEC7A)).

**Question.** Is there an explicit/"nice" description of the tensor product $\Z\otimes_{\N}\Z$, where $\Z=(\Z,\cdot,1)$ is the *multiplicative* monoid of integers?

---

**A partial description.** Eric Wofsey mentioned a really nice way to partly describe $\Z\otimes_\N\Z$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4216224/counterexamples-to-the-grothendieck-group-of-a-commutative-monoid-respecting-ten/4216247?noredirect=1#comment8752128_4216247): since $\Z \setminus \{0\} \cong\N^{\oplus\N}\oplus\Z_2$ via the map sending a non-zero integer $k= \pm 2^{n_1}3^{n_2}5^{n_3}\cdots$ to $((n_1,n_2,n_3,\ldots),\mathrm{sgn}(k))$, we may use distributivity of tensor products along direct sums to write
\begin{align*}
(\Z\setminus\{0\})\otimes_{\N}(\Z\setminus\{0\}) &\cong (\N^{\oplus\N}\oplus\Z_2)\otimes_\N(\N^{\oplus\N}\oplus\Z_2)\\
&\cong (\N^{\oplus\N}\otimes_\N\N^{\oplus\N})\oplus(\N^{\oplus\N}\otimes_\N\Z_2)\oplus(\Z_2\otimes_\N\N^{\oplus\N})\oplus(\Z_2\otimes_\N\Z_2)\\
&\cong \N^{\oplus\N}\oplus\Z_2^{\oplus\N}\\
&\cong (\Z\setminus\{0\},\cdot)^{\oplus\N}.
\end{align*}
One could then add back $0$ to each factor of $\Z\setminus\{0\}$ above, adding new elements and relations to $(\Z\setminus\{0\},\cdot)^{\oplus\N}$. What is the result of this?

Comment: Offhand, it will have a *lot* of absorptive elements--namely, $(a,0)$ and $(0,a)$ for any $a\in\Bbb Z.$ Interesting question!

Comment: I would say you consider the "wrong" tensor product resp. the "wrong" category. A more natural and convenient category is here the category of commutative monoids with zero. Notice that the multiplicative monoid of integers has a zero. The tensor product then identifies $a \otimes 0 = 0$, so the calculation is much more easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The computation of the tensor product of commutative monoids $\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}$ can be reduced to the computation of $(\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}) \otimes (\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\})$ as follows.

More generally, let $M$ be any commutative monoid (for example, $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ under multiplication). Then $M \sqcup \{0\}$ is a commutative monoid with zero which contains $M$ as a submonoid. This construction is left adjoint to the forgetful functor from commutative monoids with zero to commutative monoids. But since we only work with commutative monoids, here the universal property is a bit more complicated:
$$\hom(M \sqcup \{0\},N) \cong \{(u,f) \in M \times \hom(M,N) : u \text{ absorbs } f(M)\}.$$
The condition means that $u \cdot f(m) = u$ for all $m \in M$. Since the tensor product can also be defined by the hom-tensor-adjunction, this easily implies that (and a direct proof is also possible)
$$(M \sqcup \{0\}) \otimes N \cong (N \oplus (M \otimes N)) / (n \cdot (m \otimes n) = n)_{m \in M, n \in N}.$$
The quotient means that we mod out the smallest congruence relation which makes $n \cdot (m \otimes n)$ and $n$ equivalent, for all $m \in M$, $n \in N$. We can use this twice to deduce
$$(M \sqcup \{0\}) \otimes (N \sqcup \{0\}) \cong (M \oplus N \oplus (M \otimes N)) \sqcup \{0\}/\\ (n \cdot (m \otimes n) = n,\, m \cdot (m \otimes n) = m)_{m \in M, n \in N}.$$
As already said in my comment, notice that the tensor product is *much* easier if we work in the category of commutative monoids with zero, since in that case we just have $(M \sqcup \{0\}) \otimes_0 (N \sqcup \{0\}) \cong (M \otimes N) \sqcup \{0\}$ by general nonsense.

Comment: Thanks, Martin! This is a really nice point of view. By the way, I've noticed there's another nice way to look at it: in a sense, $\otimes_0$ is the tensor product of $\mathbb{F}_1$-algebras, of which both the multiplicative monoids $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are examples. Thus it makes more sense to take their tensor product over $\mathbb{F}_1$ (i.e. use $\otimes_0$), not over $\mathbb{N}$ (i.e. use $\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}$). (I've added an answer regarding this point, only because it ended up too long to fit into a comment.)

Comment: @Sofia Yes, sure. I was also thinking about adding that.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$Here's a remark on Martin's answer, which is unfortunately too long to post as a comment.

The point I want to mention is that the simplification noted in Martin's answer, where one considers tensor products not in $\mathsf{CMon}$, but rather in the category of commutative monoids with zero, **comes from considering tensor products not over $\N$, but over the field with one element $\F_1$.**

---

Firstly, note that we may build $\mathsf{CMon}$ by first considering $\N$-modules, which are just monoids, and then considering commutative monoids in that category, giving us commutative monoids again, i.e. $\mathsf{CMon}\cong\mathsf{CMon}(\mathsf{Mod}_{\N})$.

We can, however, start by considering not $\N$-modules, but $\F_1$-modules. These are usually thought to be pointed sets (i.e. we *define* $\mathsf{Mod}_{\F_1}\cong\mathsf{Sets}_*$). Now, the category $\mathsf{Sets}_*$ admits a monoidal structure $\otimes_{\F_1}$ obtained by defining
$$
(X,x_0)\otimes_{\F_1}(Y,y_0)=(X\times Y/{\sim},[(x_0,y_0)]),
$$
where ${\sim}$ is the equivalence relation on $X\times Y$ obtained by declaring
\begin{align*}
    (x,y_0) &\sim (x_0,y_0),\\
    (x_0,y) &\sim (x_0,y_0),
\end{align*}
for each $x\in X$ and each $y\in Y$. The monoidal unit of this tensor product is then $\mathbb{F}_1=\{0,1\}$.

Now, a commutative monoid in $(\mathsf{Mod}_{\F_1},\otimes_{\F_1},\F_1)$ is precisely a commutative monoid with zero! Indeed, it will be a triple $((A,0_A),\mu,\eta)$ consisting of

- A pointed set $(A,0_A)$;
- A morphism of pointed sets
  $$\mu\colon(A,0_A)\otimes_{\F_1}(A,0_A)\to(A,0_A),$$
  being equivalently given by a map of sets $\mu\colon A\times A\to A$, the multiplication of $A$, which is $\F_1$-bilinear in that we have
  \begin{align*}
      0_Aa &= 0_A,\\
      a0_A &= 0_A;
  \end{align*}
- A morphism of pointed sets
  $$\eta\colon(\F_1,0)\to(A,0_A),$$
  picking an element $1_A$ of $A$, its unit.

So, in a sense, commutative monoids with zero are $\F_1$-algebras, and considering the tensor product of the $\F_1$-algebra $\Z$ with itself as an $\N$-algebra will give the wrong result, the complicated tensor product in Martin's answer.

---

Finally, here's a picture I drew of the tensor product $\N\otimes_{\F_{1}}\N\cong(\N\setminus\{0\},\cdot)^{\oplus{\N}}\coprod\{0\}$, where $\mathbb{N}$ is the *multiplicative* monoid of natural numbers:

[image]

Here the blue circles depict the element $(2$, $1$, $4$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $2$, $2$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $2$, $1$, $4$, $4$, $1$, $2$, $2$, $2$, $2$, $4$, $3$, $1$, $3$, $2$, $1$, $3$, $4$, $2$, $2$, $2$, $3$, $3$, $4$, $2$, $1$, $2$, $1$, $2$, $2$, $2$, $\ldots)$ of $\N\otimes_{\F_{1}}\N\cong(\N\setminus\{0\},\cdot)^{\oplus{\N}}\coprod\{0\}$, represented as a counterclockwise spiral.

(Note that the factors of $\mathbb{N}$ in the above direct sum carry the multiplicative monoid structure, not the additive one!)

We can then picture $\Z\otimes_{\F_{1}}\Z\cong(\Z\setminus\{0\},\cdot)^{\oplus{\N}}\coprod\{0\}$ in a similar way, adding negative numbers to the above image.

Comment: I see that the monoidal unit of $\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_1}$ is the two-element pointed set, but why should we identify that with $\mathbb{F}_1$? For that matter, what's a good source for the choice $\mathsf{Mod_{\mathbb{F}_1}}=\mathsf{Sets_*}$? (I'm new to the field with one element, so apologies if this is a silly question.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm new to it as well, so I'm not very sure either. I think one expects this to hold for a reasonable theory of the field with one element because of heuristics like "$\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{1})=\Sigma_{n}$" being the "limit" of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{q})$ "as $q\to1$". From what I understand, this latter point is the one that appeared in Tits' original paper on $\mathbb{F}_{1}$ (there's a nice overview [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.05337)).

Comment: IIRC I first heard about the choice $\mathsf{Mod}_{\mathbb{F}_{1}}=\mathsf{Sets}_*$ [in the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/field+with+one+element#Modules), though I'm still learning about the reasons why such a thing would be desirable

Comment: I think one really nice reason comes from the connection with homotopy theory: the maximal subgroupoid of the category of _finite_ $\mathbb{F}_1$-modules is the groupoid of finite sets and permutations. Its classifying space has an $E_\infty$-space structure, and the abelian $\infty$-group completion of that is the sphere spectrum, the absolute base in spectral algebraic geometry!

Comment: Also, I think one has $\mathbb{F}_{1}=\{0,1\}$ in many of the current theories for the field with one element. One other reference that's particularly relevant to the subject here is [Flores' PhD thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02309), _Homological Algebra for Commutative Monoids_.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the references!

Comment: @NoahSchweber My pleasure! :)

Comment: Some other references are https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.0069 and https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2030. In particular Durov's thesis spells out the details of what is happening here.

Comment: But to get the analogy complete, notice that commutative monoids are commutative algebras in the monoidal category of $\mathbb{F}_{\emptyset}$-modules ( = sets), where $\mathbb{F}_{\emptyset}$ is the initial generalized commutative ring (see Durov).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Oh, cool!