# Examples of prime spectra of monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, monoid

Given a (pointed or unpointed) monoid $M$, one defines an *ideal* of $M$ to be a subset $I$  of $M$ such that if $a\in I$ and $r\in M$, then $ra\in I$ (and such that $0\in I$ if $M$ is pointed). A *prime ideal* $\frak p$ of $M$ is then an ideal such that if $ab\in\frak p$, then $a\in\frak p$ or $b\in\frak p$. The set of all prime ideals of $M$ can is written $\mathrm{MSpec}(M)$, and it can be made into a topological space equipped with a sheaf of monoids, giving a variant of algebraic geometry where monoids play the role of rings. Good references for this are Sections 1--2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1389) and [Ogus's book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/lectures-on-logarithmic-algebraic-geometry/70AF7196462F4CEC018E2DABA49475F6).

Lately I've been trying to compile some examples of such prime spectra, and wondering about how these relate to the usual $\mathrm{Spec}$ of a ring. So far, I've found or read about the following examples (the first five examples below come from [Martin Brandenburg's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4224188)):

- $\mathrm{MSpec}(\mathbf{N},+)=\{0,\mathbf{N}_{>0}\}$.
- $\mathrm{MSpec}(\mathbf{Z},+)=\{0\}$.
- $\mathrm{MSpec}(\mathbf{N},\cdot)=\mathrm{MSpec}(\mathbf{Z},\cdot)=\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{P})$, the powerset of the set $\mathbf{P}$ of all prime numbers.
- $\mathrm{MSpec}(\mathbf{N}\otimes_{\mathbf{N}_+}\mathbf{N})\cong\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{P}\times\mathbf{P})$.
- $\mathrm{MSpec}(\mathbf{Z}\otimes_{\mathbf{F}_1}\mathbf{Z})\cong\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{P})\times\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{P})$.
- $\mathrm{MSpec}(K)=\{(0)\}$ whenever $K^\times=K\setminus\{0\}$. In particular this applies to $\mathbf{F}_1=\{0,1\}$.
- $\mathrm{MSpec}(\mathbf{F}_1[x])=\{(0),(x)\}$.
- $\mathrm{MSpec}(\mathbf{F}_1[x,y])=\{(0),(x),(y),(x,y)\}$.
- $\mathrm{MSpec}(\mathbf{F}_1[x_1,...,x_n])=\mathcal{P}(\{x_1,...x_n\})$.
- $\mathrm{MSpec}(\mathbf{F}_1[t,t^{-1}])=\{(0),(t),(t^{-1})\}$.

Now, any ring $R$ has an associated monoid, given by keeping only multiplication, and these should give more examples. For the usual prime spectrum of a ring, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{C}[x])   &= (0)\cup\bigcup_{a\in\mathbf{C}}(x-a),\\
\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{C}[x,y]) &= (0)\cup\bigcup_{a,b\in\mathbf{C}}(x-a,y-b)\cup\{p(x,y):\text{$p\in\mathbf{C}[x,y]$ irreducible}\}\\
\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{Z}_p)    &= (0)\cup(p)
\end{align*}
and $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{Z}[x])$ is known and described in [Spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221107/spectrum-of-mathbbzx). Do we know what are the $\mathrm{MSpec}$ of the underlying pointed monoids of these four rings?

Comment: Note: this question shares part of its body with [Comparing prime spectra of rings with prime spectra of monoids](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4231723/comparing-prime-spectra-of-rings-with-prime-spectra-of-monoids), which asks about comparison maps between $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ and $\mathrm{MSpec}(R)$